# Create component which takes component prop with default anchor

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a button component that takes a component prop, I'd like to assign this prop to be an `<a>` tag by default. How is this possible?

```
const StripeConnectButton = ({ component = a }) => {
  const Button = generateButton(component);
  return <Button><span>Connect with Stripe</span></Button>
}
```

I am looking for some way of referring to an "a" tag directly, something like `React.DomComponent.a`

Answer (score 0):

```
const Anchor = (props) => <a {...props}/>

export const StripeConnectButton = ({ component = Anchor, type = 'blue', subType = 'light' }) => {
  const Button = generateButton(component, type, subType);
  return <Button><span>Connect with Stripe</span></Button>
}
```